# combine two results into one result set mysql

Tags: mysql, union

I have two queries one will return data ordered by likes and in the user city the other one return data by the distance .
so if query 1 return : id 1,2,3 (order by likes)
and query 2 return : id 4,5,6 (order by distance)
i need the final set results to be 1,2,3,4,5,6
i've tried to do union between the two queries but it's not working. any other suggestions ?

Comment: add what you have tried so far

Comment: (SELECT DISTINCT   ID, 'a' as type,...   FROM   table1  GROUP BY ID ORDER BY likesDESC
         ) union all(
        SELECT DISTINCT   ID, 'b' as type,....FROM  table1  GROUP BY ID ORDER BY distance)

Comment: but the result set returned in the first query and the result set in the second query is different from the final result

Answer (score 0):

You can use **left join** or **union** according to this [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47861/how-to-join-two-result-sets-to-query-on-output-came-from-two-statements).
**Union ALL** also works like you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892926/combining-the-results-of-two-separate-mysql-queries).

**Example: SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2**

Comment: but this still won't return as i wish . the 1,2,3,4,5,6 . so far it return 7,8,9,10,11,12...

Comment: Post your full query here please

Answer (score 0):

the solution was to put a limit to each query then the union will work correct :
(SELECT DISTINCT ID, 'a' as type,... FROM table1 GROUP BY ID ORDER BY likesDESC limit 50) union all( SELECT DISTINCT ID, 'b' as type,....FROM table1 GROUP BY ID ORDER BY distance limit 50) order by type asc.