# How to put in a <select> categories and Subcategories from a DB?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, list, while-loop

i really want to do something like this http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_optgroup
but i have The main Categories and the subcategories in a DB, and i don't really know how to manage this in a while cycle. How can i do this ? Actually the cycle is something like that, but because of my necessities i can't use it anymore

```
<select  class="form-control" id="subcategory" name="subcategory" required>
<?php
   $categories="SELECT Name,Category FROM SubCategory ORDER BY Category ASC, Name ASC;";
   $query_categories=mysqli_query($connh,$categories);

      while($rows_categories=mysqli_fetch_array($query_categories)){

echo'<option>'.$rows_categories['Category'].'/'.$rows_categories['Name'].'</option>';  
                                                                    } 
?>
</select>
```

p.s: Category is the main Category, Name is the subcategory

I want to have the main category into `<optgroup>` but because of one Category contains more than 1 subcategory, I don't know how to place `<optgroup>` in a way that it shows the main category just 1 time and not for each record.

Comment: What is it exactly that isn't working? what results are you getting/expecting? Following their example should work.

Comment: I want to have the main category into  <optgroup> but, because of one Category contains more than 1 subcategory, i don't know how to place <optgroup> in a way that it shows the main category just 1 time and not for each record

Comment: Think of it like a nest, with smaller nests inside, but without birds and straw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, need flag if current main category has added on your html, if I understand fields in your database, Name and Category has string values and you don't need two queries or two whiles but only check variable, like this:

```
<select  class="form-control" id="subcategory" name="subcategory" required>
<?php
$categories="SELECT Name,Category FROM SubCategory ORDER BY Category ASC, Name ASC;";
$query_categories=mysqli_query($connh,$categories);

$currentMainCategory = null;
while($rows_categories=mysqli_fetch_array($query_categories)){
    // check if your current category was diferent of row category
    if($currentMainCategory != $rows_categories['Category']) {
         // check if is not null (for close </optgroup>)
         if(!is_null($currentMainCategory)) {
              echo '</optgroup>';
         }
         // set your new current category for this loop
         $currentMainCategory = $rows_categories['Category'];
         echo '<optgroup label="'. $rows_categories['Category'] .'">';
    }
    // do not forget put value of this category if you needed
    echo'<option>' . $rows_categories['Name'] . '</option>';  
}

// then check again for close last optgroup if is opened
if(!is_null($currentMainCategory)) {
   echo '</optgroup>';
}
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not too far off from accomplishing your basic goal, which is to display the categories and sub-categories in an optgroup.

You can either:

1. Query MySQL with two separate queries and combine them using PHP against both the `SubCategory` and `Category` tables.
2. Perform two `foreach` loops, each containing an `optgroup` for the respective `Category` and `SubCategory` results.

*or*

1. Query MySQL with one query using `OUTER JOIN` to retrieve one result set against both the `SubCategory` and `Category` tables (possibly even a `UNION`).
2. Perform two `foreach` loops, each containing an `optgroup` for the respective `Category` and `SubCategory` results, but only display the `Category` results if it came from the `Category` table and vice versa.

Here's some reference material:

MySQL Joins: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

MySQL Union: [Combining the results of two separate MySQL queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892926/combining-the-results-of-two-separate-mysql-queries)

PHP Foreach loop: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

PHP Array Merging: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_merge.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
<select  class="form-control" id="subcategory" name="subcategory" required>
<?php
$categories="SELECT Name,Category FROM SubCategory ORDER BY Category ASC, Name ASC;";
$query_categories=mysqli_query($connh,$categories);
$category_name_old = '';
while($rows_categories=mysqli_fetch_array($query_categories)){

    if($rows_categories['Category'] != $category_name_old) {
        echo "<optgroup label=".$rows_categories['Category'].">";
        echo "<option>".$rows_categories['Name']."</option>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<option>".$rows_categories['Name']."</option>";
    }
    $category_name_old = $rows_categories['Category'];
    if($category != $category_name_old) {
        echo "</optgroup>";
    }
}  
                                                                    } 
?>
</select>
```

You can do like this

Answer (score 0):

Create an array with your main categories, with subcategories as a sub-array.

```
<select  class="form-control" id="subcategory" name="subcategory" required>
<?php
$option_list = array();

$categories="SELECT Name,Category FROM SubCategory ORDER BY Category ASC, Name ASC;";
$query_categories=mysqli_query($connh,$categories);

while($rows_categories=mysqli_fetch_array($query_categories)){  
    $option_list[$rows_categories['Category']][] = $rows_categories['Name'];
}

// this is what we're aiming for
// $option_list = array("Maincat1"=>array("subcat1","subcat2","subcat3"),"Maincat2"=>array("subcat4","subcat5"));


foreach($option_list as $maincat=>$subcats){
    echo "<optgroup label='".$maincat."'>";
    foreach($subcats as $subcat){
        echo "<option value='$subcat'>$subcat</option>";
    }
    echo "</optgroup>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password,$mysql_database) or die("Could not connect database");
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"select distinct Category from SubCategory");
echo '<select  class="form-control" id="subcategory" name="subcategory" required>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){  
    echo '<optgroup label="'. $row['Category'] .'">';
     $data =  mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT Name,Category FROM SubCategory where Category = '".$row['Category']."'");
while($value = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){  
    echo '<option>'. $value['Name'] .'</option>';
}
 echo '</optgroup>';
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```